# How to use Spring batch , Quartz, scheduler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch-tasklet

I'm trying to figure out how to implement Spring Batch + Quartz or Scheduler to the following business logic.

Environment:
I have a reservation database table which multiple reservations can be created by a single client (Client Table(One): Reservation Table(Many) relations)

Business logic:
In a specific reservation state, the client is suppose to receive a notification by email at (reservation state that has been updated by an admin update time) + 1hour

Is there a simple example that i can refer to?

I tried using Quartz library but couldn't quite understand the concept of its use-cases and was not able to achieve what I was planning to develop

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch does not provide support to schedule job executions. Once you have defined your Spring Batch job, it is up to you to use the library you want to schedule its execution when needed.

If you plan to use the [scheduling capabilities](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling) provided by Spring Framework, you can create a scheduled method as follows:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JobScheduler {

    private final Job job;

    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    public JobScheduler(Job job, JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        this.job = job;
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * *")
    public void launchJob() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();

        this.jobLauncher.run(this.job, jobParameters);
    }

}
```

For quartz, you can refer to the quick start guide: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/quick-start.html

Comment: the problem that i had with the question above was due to lack of Quartz Scheduling information.

After creating Quartz database tables and configuring them with my project, Scheduling each datas led to Quartz scheduler module handling and managing the way i wanted to.

Anyways thank you for your time on encouraging me to actually test out some of the scheduling features instead of looking for the right one.